# How to use the rear camera instead of the front camera on a teachable machine

Tags: javascript, camera, webcam, teachable-machine

// More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

```
// the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
const URL = "./my_model/";

let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

// Load the image model and setup the webcam
async function init() {
    const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
    const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";
   

    // load the model and metadata
    // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
    // or files from your local hard drive
    // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
    model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
    maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();
    
    // Convenience function to setup a webcam

    const size = 350;
    const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
    webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(size, size, flip); // width, height, flip
    await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
    await webcam.play();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    // append elements to the DOM
    document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
    labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
    for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
        labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    }
}

async function loop() {
    webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
    await predict();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Currently, it is producing a program that can produce food-related information by filming food with a mobile phone rear camera using a learning machine.

I want to use the back camera in this part, but only the front camera keeps coming out. I'd appreciate it if you could help me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(375, 375, flip); // width, height, flip
    await webcam.setup({ facingMode: "environment" }); 
    await webcam.play();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

> Adicione a função setup o seguinte código:

```
 await webcam.setup({ facingMode: "environment" });
```

> Esse código solicita acesso a webcam traseira de forma automática. Após isso altere o flip para false. Dessa forma a imagem não ficara invertida.

```
const flip = false;
```

Comment: There is no good use of code only answers. Please take some time to right an explanation to it

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)